# Send email gives SSLProtocolException

Tags: android, email, ssl-certificate, sendmail

I am using this sample code:

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

I am trying to use my own server email to send email without intent on Android.

I know that sample is configured to works only with Gmail.

**I have changed:**

```
    _host = "smtp.myserver.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "587"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "587"; // default socketfactory port
```

**and this on MainActivity:**

```
Mail m = new Mail("username@myserver.com", "password"); //to my sever email
```

I just set the right information on Outlook, and it works, I could send and receive from this email.

**Server allow this setup:**

POP3
SMTP
IMAP
WebMail
Mobile/PDA

**Question:**

I need to add/change something more? Or this sample can´t work with other then gmail.

**I got this error on Logcat:**

```
  01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094): Could not send email
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.semhora.com, port: 587;
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   nested exception is:
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1e4490: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:683 0xad12957d:0x00000000)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at com.example.sendemailtester.Mail.send(Mail.java:102)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at com.example.sendemailtester.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-31 21:07:08.989: E/MailApp(17094): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1e4490: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used this wrapper, but the code is assuming SSL support while it appears your port 587 server does not support SSL. Comment out these 2 lines

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

and set this line from false to true

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

That might help out.

Comment: If I do that, I got: 01-31 21:31:22.989: E/MailApp(18069): com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Access Denied
01-31 21:31:22.989: E/MailApp(18069):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1515)

Comment: Is the SMTP server you're connecting to configured to allow you to relay mail through it? A 550 5.7.1 access denied means your code successfully connected to the SMTP server, but then the server denied you.

Comment: I dont know, if I can use this email with Outlook, that means that it allow relay mail through it or this means nothing?

Comment: You should be able to relay with the proper credentials, which you're passing in your constructor. Try turning on _debuggable in the Mail class and see if it gives you anything useful in the output. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, debug mode said that I also need to change m.setFrom("username@myserver.com"); , now it works.